# Is possible to read full network traffic on mobile?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, networking

I'm building an application to measure internet speed with Flutter using the [TCP](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-transmission-control-protocol-tcp/) protocol. In the app I read how much time a file takes to upload and download, let's say 50MB. When I make a measurement with Wireshark to read full traffic, the headers of the segments and the retransmitted packets makes the data flow to be higher than 50MB, this size it's different each time I run the app and this makes the test not accurate. How can I capture the retransmitted packages and the headers of the segments within the app?

I've tried with [Dio](https://pub.dev/packages/dio) and [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) packages, haven't found a way to measure full traffic with this libraries. If there is a way on native Android or iOS please comment.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the network connection and topology, esp. how Wireshark is reading the data? (WiFi vs. cellular, what type of network service (5G, what kind of WiFi, etc.)

Comment: I'm emulating an android device within a mac, connected via hostpot to 4G and 3G mobile data, then I filter on Wireshark by ip.src_host/ip.dst+host. The measure in Wireshark is ok, the payload value is the expected, but in the mobile app I can only measure the payload, not the headers of each segment and the retransmitted packets, that's what I want to achieve.

Comment: I get it. The network overhead statistics would probably live inside the OS layer (network stack). Classically this was the world of SNMP. I couldn't find anything via a speed-google.